# How to fix Agent issue while running in OBIEE11.1.1.7.0

Tags: analytics, scheduler, obiee

I'm trying to run agent which is having scheduling options like..

In schedule tab of agent

Enabled  :true
Frequency:once
Start    :03/21/2014 **06:30:00** PM
Re-run Agent Every: not selected
         Until    : not selected

I'm running agent by **06:25:00** PM. Here I need to get the notification mail by **6:30** PM. But the issue is I'm getting notifications mail by **6:25** PM as well as **6:30** PM.

Will any body help on this issue......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we run agent in OBiee then it will take the option as RUNNOW. Thats why getting notification by current time also.